# Not all the files in the repo appear when I clone from gitlab

Tags: git, macos, terminal, gitlab, git-clone

I can’t seem to figure it out and it’s been hours. I cloned a repo but not everything inside it appears. Basically I want to clone a repo that has a certain .ipynb that I want to run on jupyternotebook, but it’s not included when I clone the repo

Answer (score 1):

`git clone` clones everything. Two options come to mind:

- The file is not present in the `master` branch, in which case you first need to checkout a branch that contains the file that you want: `git checkout branch`
- The file is present but hidden, like dotfiles usually are. You can verify via terminal if the file actually is present: `ls -a`

Comment: Thank you, `ls -a` ended up showing the other files that weren't showing up. Why they were hidden like this, I don't understand.